# How to Sync Android App with other devices

Tags: android, synchronization

I'm developing an Android App (not a game) and I'm wondering if there is a way to let the user sync his app state with other devices. I've only found the "Google Play Games Services" but they seems to be restricted for games only.

Is there a similar service for non game apps? Or is it OK to use the "Google Play Games Services" for non game apps? Have someone allready done it?

Comment: What kind of data are you want to sync?

Comment: you could use google's firebase and store whatever you are trying to sync in their realtime database. http://firebase.google.com/

Comment: I got a recommendation to use [couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com) db for sync propose. But I haven't tried it so far.